# What is the process of acquiring a streaming license?

Tags: anime-production, streaming-sites

When a streaming site decides they want to stream a particular anime series or movie, what steps do they take from start to finish?

- Who emails whom?
- Does the streaming site hire additional staff like translators, censors/editors to add subtitles and hide/blur nude body parts?
- Which professional and legal services need to be paid?
- How much does each step cost?

Comment: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2012-06-11 has a pretty good description of the licensing process, and it seems like at least some streaming sites (like Crunchyroll) have some sort of agreement to stream shows licensed by distribution companies, but I'm having trouble finding answers to the rest of yoru questions.

Comment: Might answer your question https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/42422/1458