# How to get a license to stream anime on my website?

Tags: licensing, streaming-sites

I am planning on making a website for streaming anime (legally). I would like to know how can I obtain the license to host and stream anime?

I would like to know from where I can get the license, who should I approach and what all things should I consider when getting a license.

Comment: Strongly related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33593/7579.

Comment: As suggested a comment of the other post, i recommand checking this article : http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2012-06-11

Comment: might answer your question https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/42422/1458