# Can fans convince a streaming site to show a certain anime?

Tags: anime-production, streaming-sites

If a streaming site, for whatever reason, doesn't have a certain anime of which you're a fan, can you gather enough votes in online petitions or facebook likes to convince the site to start streaming it?
When could this work, and when would this be hopeless? For example: do studios decide not to work with specific streaming sites, regions or audiences of less than N viewers?

Comment: Probably depends on the site.  They have to weigh the cost of getting a license and putting the content up vs. how much they can make by doing so.  I can't imagine there is a one size fits all policy for this.

Comment: then I'd like to know how it's calculated, but I asked that in another question already

Comment: Well, hopefully that question gets a good answer that can help you.  Ultimately, I believe it still depends on the site.  How they calculate how much they are likely to make along with other things is going to vary.  It will also differ between sites what they consider "worth it" vs. not.  I don't think we can give you a definitive answer.  If you are curious about a specific site, try contacting them and see if they can give you any guidance about what they would need to consider putting a show on their site.

Comment: The devil's in the details.  Likely guesses would be if the studio plans for an international release, and there are a lot of series that never plan for or didn't originally plan for one.

Answer (score -2):

In most cases: No. They don't care about the fans, and care about profits. Most streaming sites have licenses to stream that show, which often enough is for exclusivity, such as with Netflix, or Amazon Prime. The licenses for these shows are either expensive from competition for it, or not worth the cost because of lack of response for the series. In the former case, the streaming site you're petitioning can do nothing about it, considering some other place will most likely already have the license, and in the latter case, can't see enough profits coming from it to make it worth the cost.

Comment: Well, I suppose the question was "How many fans (or response, as you say) is enough to make it happen?" and what you say is nothing I don't know already.